# Python script doesn't print spanish characters

Tags: python

If I print a spanish word from the command line it works fine:

```
>>> print("Ñandú")
Ñandú
>>>
```

But if I put the same line into a python script and execute it from the os, Spanish characters are not shown:

```
$ tail ñandu.py

print("Ñandú")

$ py ñandu.py

¦and¦               <---------- That is what it prints intstead of "Ñandú".
```

The same happen if I use double or simple quotation marks.
I guess it is an encoding issue, but I didn't manage to solve it.

I running it from a Git Bash session running on Windows 10. (I'm using a corporate computer, I don't have many options to replace the os).

Python version is 3.8.1 and system code page is 850.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "execute it from the os"? What operating system and terminal/console are you using?

Comment: Hi, two questions that may be related to your problem: what version of python are using? what is your operational system?

Comment: In python 2.7 and 3.8 is everything ok. You can also try `print(u"Ñandú")` instead.

Comment: Looks like you are probably on Windows. What is your system code page? Could you please [edit] your question to clarify this? If Windows is not central to your use case, replacing it could help.

Comment: @tripleee I'm on windows too and everything works - OS is not a problem. I guess it's rather something like iron python anaconda or sth. like that, but let's wait for OP's response.

Comment: Hi, I running it from a Git Bash session running on Windows 10. (I'm using a corporate computer, I don't have many options to replace the os). 
Python version is 3.8.1
Using print(u"Ñandú") didn't help

Comment: what is `py` aliased to?

Comment: Good hint Khuynh! Apparently, there was no alias for 'py' (I don't know what was it executing then). I tried witn "python ñandu.py" instead and it worked fine.
Thank you!